# Illegal to give lawyer a bonus for getting an acquittal?

Tags: criminal-law, attorney-fees

I recently found out that in Massachusetts it is illegal for a lawyer to accept a bonus for obtaining an acquittal in a criminal case. In other words, if a client says I will pay you an hourly rate plus a $50,000 bonus if I get acquitted, then it would be illegal under Massachusetts law for the lawyer to accept that arrangement.

Do other states have the same law or is this a Massachusetts special?